# I think I've called that function but no brackets are attached beside the function name

Tags: javascript, function, promise, callback, invoke

Why is no bracket needed when invoking the `getPost` function at the end?

I'm confused by function brackets.

I try understanding the promise chain. The original code is as follows:

```
const posts = [
    { title: 'Post One', body: 'This is Post One' },
    { title: 'Post Two', body: 'This is Post Two' },
];

//(Three posts listed - callback right after post)
function createPost(post) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            posts.push(post);
            const error = false;
            if (!error) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject("Error. Something went wrong")
            }
        }, 2000);
    });
}

function getPosts() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let output = '';
        posts.forEach((post, index) => {
            output += `<li>${post.title}</li>`
        })
        document.body.innerHTML = output;
    }, 1000)
};

createPost({ title: 'Post Three', body: 'This is Post Three' })
    .then(getPosts)
    .catch (err => console.log(err));
```

I wonder why it should not be `.then(getPosts())`? Previous answers of functions without brackets are used to refer to the function only, and not invoking the function at that moment (i.e. `.then` in my case).

But I think I intend to invoke the function at the `.then` position, so that the console will print out the text below (and this is the correct result):

```
Post One
Post Two
Post Three
```

In what way I think it wrong?

If the `.then` indeed acts as a reference only, where is the actual position for the function to be invoked?

Also, if I do add the () for the getPosts, it returns just Post One and Post Two. Why should it be so?

Comment: `then` accepts a callback function as input argument. `getPosts` will be invoked by `then`.

Comment: getPost() means invoking the function, getPost is function reference you got it right

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi that means the point of invoking the getPosts is .then, not the getPosts, therefore no need to add bracket for getPosts?

Comment: Because `.then(getPosts())` passes whatever the function *returns* as the callback for `.then` to invoke?

Comment: @ronzenith I don't really understand what are you asking, please try to research `callbacks` and `higher order functions`.

Answer (score 1):

getPosts() means invoking the function, getPosts is function reference you got it right

Now then takes a callback which will be get called when promise get resolved ( or when resolve method in promise get invoke ) So you need to pass the reference of getPosts in then

When you pass getPosts(), it will get called immediately so prints only two posts which are already present in posts array without waiting for promise to get resolved

Comment: Thanks. Seems that the getPosts takes action at .then(), while getPosts is the reference. In lay language, it would mean after I push Post Three to the posts array, I loop over the array and deliver the three titles to the browser.

Comment: Go through this article - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise it will give you proper understanding about promises and how they work